# Custom Post type and Custom taxonomy with URL rewrite worked but template did not

Tags: url-rewriting, taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

I search a lot but couldn't get, just got partial answer , I declared custom post type "store" with taxonomy "city", what I am trying is to make list of store based on city list and make URL like
*post type  = store*
*taxonomy = city*
`<posttype slug><taxonomy term>`

*.com/store/tokyo/my_store_name*

some how I achieved it by using this code. 
[Custom Post Type / Taxonomy Slug / Post Title with post type archive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96126/custom-post-type-taxonomy-slug-post-title-with-post-type-archive)
but now how use custom template , I tried "archive-city.php, single-store.php, taxonomy-city.php, and couple of more standard combination but all landed on 404.

Comment: if you're receiving 404s, then the code you linked is not working, it has nothing to do with templates. have you flushed rewrite rules?

Comment: Yes I did, here is code of my Post type

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_custom_post_work() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Store', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Store', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Store' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Store' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Store' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Store' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Store' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Store' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Store' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Store found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No store found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Our Store'
    );
$args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our works and work specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'store/%store_location%')
    );
    register_post_type( 'ss_store', $args );  

}


add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_work' );

$labels = array(
        'name'                       => 'Cities',
        'singular_name'              => 'City',
        'menu_name'                  => 'City',
        'all_items'                  => 'All Cities',
        'parent_item'                => 'Parent City',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent City:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'New City Name',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add New City',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit City',
        'update_item'                => 'Update City',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate City with commas',
        'search_items'               => 'Search Cities',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Cities',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used Cities',
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        //'hierarchical'               => false,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'query_var'                  => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
        'has_archive'                => true

    );


    register_taxonomy( 'city', 'ss_store', $args );


}
add_action( 'init', 'mav_taxonomies_work', 0 );

add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);    

function filter_post_type_link( $post_link, $id = 0, $leavename = FALSE ) {
    if ( strpos('%store_location%', $post_link) === 'FALSE' ) {
      return $post_link;
    }
    $post = get_post($id);
    if ( !is_object($post) || $post->post_type != 'ss_store' ) {
      return $post_link;
    }
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'store_location');
    if ( !$terms ) {
      return str_replace('store/%store_location%/', '', $post_link);
    }
    return str_replace('%store_location%', $terms[0]->slug, $post_link);
}


add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
add_action( 'wp_loaded','my_flush_rules' );  

/// flush  
function my_flush_rules(){
    $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );
            global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
} 

// Also, you will have to write rewrite rules for your custom post type for your proposed URI structure to work.

// Add the below code to your theme's functions.php file:


 `
// Adding a new rule    
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )    
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['store/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=ss_store';
    $newrules['store/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=ss_work&paged=$matches[1]';
    $newrules['store/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=ss_store&city=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
    //print_r($rules);
    return $newrules + $rules;
```

this is the code I used... permalinks are formatted as wanted but now template not loading...404

Comment: Please add your code to your question unless you want to answer your own question with a working solution. What happens when you re-save your permalinks?

Comment: Nothing happens, permalink structure is ok, Reseting permalink from Setting/Permalink still results same, 404, even i am unable to see custom post single view..on default template.