# Custom Post type and Taxonomy in post URL error

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have added a custom post type and assigned taxonomy to it by following this tutorial: [Custom Post Type / Taxonomy Slug / Post Title with post type archive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96126/custom-post-type-taxonomy-slug-post-title-with-post-type-archive?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I have two terms in custom taxonomy .

1. work-cat-1
2. work-cat-2

when a post is under 'work-cat-1' the url is http://localhost/wordpress/our-work/work-cat-1/test-work/

if I change the url in the address bar and replace "**work-cat-1**" with any random word like "**abcdef**" then the link should not work .

But 
localhost/wordpress/our-work/*abcdef*/test-work/

is showing the post linked to

localhost/wordpress/our-work/*work-cat-1*/test-work/

How to resolve this issue ??

Comment: If you want to enforce the correct term, you have to modify the default query to incorporate that data. The answer is similar to the last part of [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167339/4771), with taxonomy instead of meta parameters, though I question how necessary this is, considering the unlikely case where some random string is going to end up in the middle of your permalink.

Comment: Thanks !! That answer you mentioned helped..Now I'm playing with that